# PayPal Express Checkout broken in Magento Version 1.9.3.6 with HTTPS

Tags: paypal, ssl, https

we switched from HTTP to HTTPS / SSL and now the PayPal Express checkout is broken.

when you try to pay with paypal, you get redirected by to cart view and see the error message ***Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error).***

what do we have to do? change something in PayPal account?

Comment: Have a look here, you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur